# Read() in C/C++ - regarding what is read vs buffer size

Tags: c++, c, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to read a message (string/text) from the server, and I set the buffer size really large (buffer_size = 1000) so that I only need to read once from the server.

So my question is if the message is exactly 10 bytes, and I call read(socket, buffer, buffer_size), then is it gonna read only 10 bytes, since it is less than the actual buffer size? I guess I'm just curious about the behavior of the call in case what is read is actually not as much as what is expected.

Also if I call the read() again, will it overwrite what is in the buffer? By that I mean empty the buffer and overwrite it with new input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're presumably using TCP, which is a streaming protocol - message boundaries are not sent, just the stream of bytes. So even if the server does a single write, you may end up having to do several reads to get the data.

Keep reading until either you have enough bytes, or read returns 0 (which means EOF).

If a read gets you N bytes, and it's not enough, then you need to issue another read targeting buffer + N.

Answer (score 1):

Please read man of [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)

As of

> Also if I call the read() again, will it overwrite what is in the buffer? By that I mean empty the buffer and overwrite it with new input.

Well, read will overwrite the buff but not gone to empty buffer for you, you have to do it youself.

Answer (score 0):

The `read(int fd, void *buffer, size_t count)` function will read up to `count` bytes from file descriptor `fd` into `buffer`, so if there are only `10 bytes` for reading it will only read `10 bytes`. And no, it will not empty `buffer` and overwrite it's content, it will just overwrite the bytes read from the file descriptor.

Comment: Thanks! One other question is if the read/write call doesnt read/write as many bytes as requested, how do I read/write the remaining bytes? I read somewhere that just simply call read/write again and it will do the job. Is that right?

Comment: yes you call it until it returns `0` (meaning no data left to read) or an error.

Comment: I mean `0` means no data left to read and `<0` means an error, but you must read until one of the two occurs.